# How to make the blades accessible for both user and admin while I am using two middlewares, one for user auth and second one for admin?

Tags: laravel-5, controller, routes, middleware, laravel-authorization

I have 2 different tables, user and admin. There are 2 middleware as I told you before. I want to make the blade accessible for both user and admin.
I'm using middleware in the controller. Like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use the middleware in the controller? You could use middleware on route and have a specific admin and user route

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other requirement to have the middleware in the controller you could apply it to the route like so

```
Route::middleware('user')->group(function () {
    //your user routes here
});

Route::middleware('admin')->group(function () {
    //your admin routes here
});
```